# Wrapped floating point type with built-in epsilon

Tags: haskell, floating-point

I'm working on some geometrical calculations that will require me to compare coordinates based on Doubles. I usually deal with the floating point inaccuracies in this situation by including some artificial epsilon. This is common and there is lots of information available on this topic.

http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

My thought is to wrap Double in a newtype and implement Eq and Ord using epsilon. This seems like such an obvious concept that either its already been done and must be in a library on Hackage or there is something obviously wrong with the concept I haven't thought of yet. So my questions, Does anyone know of an existing module that contains a similar type (I did a quick search and did not see anything)? Or, is this a bogus idea? Thanks.

Comment: One problem with that approach is that equality is no longer transitive. That need not be a deal-breaker, though.

Comment: Is `Eq`'s `(==)` assumed to be transitive anywhere? Maybe it's in a rewrite rule somewhere. I just checked the 2010 report, it's not mentioned there at the very least.

Comment: Are you looking for [interval arithmetic](https://www.google.com/search?q=interval+arithmetic&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari)?

Comment: @Eric, That would be the ultimate representation. Might be a little overkill for this specific instance. Thanks. I had read a little about interval arithmetic a while ago, this was a good reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bogus idea. One approach is to create types that allow you write floating point expressions which in order to be evaluated require an piece of configuration data - i.e. the value of epsilon. This would work much like the Reader monad.

An nice approach to this problem is given in:

http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/types.html#Prepose

and an efficient implementation for GHC may be found on hackage in the reflection package.

Comment: Another possibility is just to create a new type class with new operators for the approximate comparisons: `~=`, `~<`, '~>` - then you could avoid having to wrap the standard types with `newtype`. To have a configurable epsilon you might want to look into using an implicit parameter - http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Implicit_parameters - it's a lot less involved than the dependent typing approach outlined in the Prepose paper.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. I had forgotten that newtype requires the use of both constructors in pattern matching etc. A little clumsy for this application. Thanks.